# How to get tolerance in forward direction not backward

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle, verify, fault-tolerance

I know the question can be unclear. I will attempt to explain.

I have a scenario where I need to verify for a sequence of values `5,10,15,20....,` only that the system that produces sequence is not very accurate that sometimes it can miss the values or repeat couple of values like `5, 10,10,20,25,30,40.`

So as you can see there is a tolerance of `5-10`.

This is okay. I have to verify that the sequence does not go backwards like `5,10,15,10.. or 5,10,9,....`

I need to write a *PASS FAIL* condition using a logic that Passes if it sees monotonically increasing sequence with occasional misses or repeats, fails if it sees values go backwards or differ by more than `10 (like 5, 20, 15...)`

Can someone please help me identify right logic for this

Comment: What is the sequence? Is it a list, or a file, or a stream? Please show some code.

Comment: Do you have variables that print out the sequences is? If you do check if like if (b>a) { return false }

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
def validate(li):
    return all(x==y or 5<=(y-x)<=10 for x,y in zip(li,li[1:]))
```

If you really want to assert that your data originates from a monotonically-increasing-by-5 source, you also might want to tack on some logic that the max value of your sequence (`li[-1]`) is approximately `5*len(li) + li[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple:

```
previousVal = ###
actualVal = ###

difference = actualVal - previousVal

if 0 <= difference <= 10  ## Change acc. to your requirement. Unclear if its 5-10 or 0-10
    #PASS
else:
    #FAIL!
```

If its a list that you are getting as input, then you can zip the original list with a shifted-by-1 list, and iterate over the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence is a list, `l`, you can use this:

```
'FAIL' if any(l[i]<l[i-1] or l[i]-l[i-1]>10 for i in xrange(1,len(l))) else 'PASS'
```